# How to do Something like a transpose in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL, where I just change my job and I need to use SQL quite frequently.

Previously, I used to work with Excel which I can easily do the following conversion from picture 1 to picture 2 by using a pivot table

[image]

[image]

Where I would like to work on the original data source like in picture 1,
and add a few new columns in picture 2 which correspond to each type in the dimension 'customer type'.

I would like to know to how I can achieve this in SQL.

Comment: Search for *t-sql PIVOT* or search this site for *dynamic pivot* if the columns are variable in number/content

Comment: You can use `PIVOT` statement and develop it for your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`PIVOT` query](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)
The examples on in the link are pretty self explanatory; you do something like this:

```
SELECT Brand, Shop, Adult, SeniorCitizen, Student
FROM YourTable
PIVOT (
    SUM(CostOfPurchase) FOR CustomerType IN (Adult, SeniorCitizen, Student)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT brand, shop, 
MAX(CASE WHEN [Customer Type] = 'Adult' THEN [Cost of purchase] ELSE 0 END) AS adult, 
MAX(CASE WHEN [Customer Type] = 'Senior Citizen' THEN [Cost of purchase] ELSE 0 END) AS [senior],
MAX(CASE WHEN [Customer Type] = 'Student' THEN [Cost of purchase] ELSE 0 END) AS sutudent FROM table1
GROUP BY brand, shop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select brand, type, 
max(case when customer_type='Adult' then cost end) as Adult,
max(case when customer_type='Senior Citizen' then cost end) as Senior Citizen,
max(case when customer_type='Student' then cost end) as Student
from table
Group by brand, type
```

If the values are dynamic, you can try http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10840/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server-2005.aspx

Comment: Some `"`'s or `[]`'s needed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with PIVOT and dynamic SQL (that will save your time from editing query if new `[Customer Type]`s are added):

```
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max),
        @query nvarchar(max)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((
SELECT DISTINCT ','+QUOTENAME([Customer Type]) 
FROM YourTable
FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'')

SELECT @query = '
SELECT  *
FROM YourTable
PIVOT (
    SUM([Cost of purchase]) FOR [Customer Type] IN ('+@cols+')
) as pvt
ORDER BY Brand, Shop'

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Output:

```
Brand   Shop    Adult   Senior Citizen  Student
AAA     1       32343   32288           29618
AAA     2       36209   29060           26354
AAA     3       29902   11137           46743
BBB     1       33625   411127          30001
BBB     2       43168   18657           18243
BBB     3       14951   22626           23542
CCC     1       22194   41338           45287
CCC     2       38443   39329           10384
CCC     3       27422   29866           42628
```